# In a Zsh auto completion script, how can i test a arg variable against a backslash?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to edit the [`git` completion script](https://github.com/glidenote/hub-zsh-completion/blob/master/_git), and would like to test the `opt_args`for a backslash

**Current code:** this test for `--no-index`, i would like to check for `\`

```
  if [[ -n ${opt_args[(I)--no-index]} ]]; then
    _alternative 'files::_files' && ret=0
    return ret
  fi
```

I tried `if [[ -n ${opt_args[(I)\]} ]];`, `if [[ -n ${opt_args[(I)'\']} ]];` and `if [[ -n ${opt_args[(I)/\]} ]];` but it does not work, any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The argument can be tested as follow:

```
      if [[ $line[1] == *\/* ]]; then
        _alternative 'files::_files' && ret=0
        return ret
      fi
```